# Replace some vector values with NA is not working if the code is put into a function

Tags: r, function

Say

```
x <- c(543271979, 64943072624964203854, 6239846230)
```

Below command give the expected results

```
 x[(which(nchar(x)!=10))] <- NA
```

but if I write it in a function it throws incorrect results. Function is as below:

```
function(x){
    clean_vector <- x[(which(nchar(x)!=10))] <- NA
    return(clean_vector)
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can chain assign like that with `[` methods. Simply using `x[(which(nchar(x)!=10))] <- NA; return(x)` should work..

Comment: Also the `which()` is overkill. `which()` is used to return the positions of the logical `TRUE`s. As long as you only need indexing, `x[nchar(x) != 10]` is sufficient.

Comment: x[nchar(x) != 10] works well too but if i have to embed this command in a function what are the possible ways to do it. Can you please advise.

Comment: If you need both the original `x` and `clean_vector`: `function(x){    clean_vector <- x; clean_vector[nchar(clean_vector) != 10] <- NA; more_stuff_goes_here; return(something) }`.